# git push heroku master cannot merge with master branch due to unrelated histories

Tags: git, heroku, zsh

I've got an app in heroky named `my-app` that I'm trying to update using `git push heroku master` but whenever I do that, I get this error

```
To https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I try `git pull heroku master`

```
From https://git.heroku.com/my-app
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

when I try `git pull heroku master --allow-unrelated-histories`:

```
From https://git.heroku.com/my-app
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

How can I replace the code in the heroku master branch with the code on the master branch of the `my-app` repo?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting and redeploying my heroku app. I did this because I knew all the code I had locally and on the master branch in git was correct and I was fine to lose all the other code on heroku.